# Do I have to file two tax returns if I am employed and self-employed?

Tags: taxes, canada, small-business, ontario, hst

I am employed full-time by an employer that does tax deductions but I also work freelance on the side which I do have a business number for and collect HST.

I know I have to fill out the HST forms (sales, total hst, total ITCs, net tax) and send them all the HST I collected (minus HST on expenses).

When I'm actually filling out the income tax what do I fill out? A business return and add personal employment income? A personal return and add self employed income (can I do deductions this way?) or a both?

Comment: For your business, are you incorporated, or a sole proprietor?

Comment: sole proprieter/small supplier - just have an HST # for collecting, no incorporation or anything.